# how to resolve opencv cmake building error: could NOT findJNI on linuxmint?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, cmake, linux-mint

I am trying to do a project combining opencv with java. I am trying to build opencv using cmake. But every time I am trying to do so following error comes up.
command I used is,

`cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..`

The error message received is:

```
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY 
JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
```

I have tried every thing by searching the threads here,  but couldn't find the solution for this. 
Things I have tried are:

1. **Setting the environmental variables** for java using `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`
2. **editing the FindJNI.cmake file** under cmake installed directory

I am using cmake 3.0. and linux mint as the OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Could not find JNI", building OpenCV on Raspberry Pi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529800/how-to-resolve-could-not-find-jni-building-opencv-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: already tried every thing in that post. still couldn't solve the problem